# git pull with ansible

Tags: git, ansible

with this playbook I get no errors and it runs on ubuntu against userhome slash git. The autput is a bit loud but I can't see why it does not properly pull latest changes from the remote server

```
- hosts: local
  vars:
     ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/env python3"

   tasks:
   - name: find git directories
     find:
       paths: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/git"
       file_type: directory
     register: found_directories

   - name: update repos
     git:
       repo: "{{ item.path }}/.git"
       dest: "{{ item.path }}"
       version: master
       update: yes
     with_items: "{{ found_directories.files }}"
```

any idea why the git module does not pull latest changes from github ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for those interested in how to update homefolder/git... repo directories with a git pull. The only solution I found was with a shell command.

```
- hosts: local
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/env python3"

  tasks:
   - name: find git directories
     find:
       paths: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/git"
       file_type: directory
     register: found_directories

   - name: pull latest changes
     shell: git pull 
     args:
       chdir: "{{ item.path }}"
       executable: /bin/bash
     with_items: "{{ found_directories.files }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `repo: "{{ item.path }}/.git"` in the second task means that the git repo is stored in the `.git` repository (if `{{ item.path }}` equals `/home/ninja/git`, that means that the git project is stored in `/home/ninja/git/.git` and that you would find the `.git` directory in `/home/ninja/git/.git/.git`).

I think you just made an error by suffixing `.git` and that your project is actually in `/home/ninja/git`. If that is correct, just remove the `.git` part in the `repo` parameter.

Comment: it seems you are right in a sense. Still it does not pull anything new

Comment: When you go in the directory manually and execute the command `git status`, do you see any modified files in the directory? Because the ansible git module default behaviour is to not pull is there are local modified files. Also, if you do a `git pull` manually, does the pull works? If not, it may be a ssh/network/permissions issue.

Comment: very odd now even a command line git pull is not working. I am pretty sure it worked for many repos ...that I wanted a script for that

Comment: Then this is not an Ansible issue but a network / ssh key / account permissions issue. You have to fix that first, ensure that it works manually, then only go again with your Ansible.

Comment: actually the ansible Job runs as it is but ater git pull is not doing anything. Lokks like it just getting the files and not doing a git pull...odd

Comment: I don't get it. Does the `git pull` works manually? If not, it will not work with Ansible either.

Comment: first it does, than I run the ansible command, afterwards it doesn't anymore

Comment: Try running your playbook with the `-vv` option to have more information.

Comment: good one thanks....now it's clear that the Approach is wrong at all as the repo must be the remot address not the Folder itself. or I would have to use a workfolder...I have to rethink that..maybe just use the Shell module